# Change MainActivity Variable from Other Class

Tags: java, android, android-intent

Im Sorry, Please Help. I have MainActivity and 2 IntentService. I want to change my MainActivity  Variables (kabupaten and provinsi) from variables that get from FetchAddressIntentService. Then, i want to give that variables (kabupaten and provinsi) to another intent (ParseXmlCuaca).. The problem is kabupaten and provinsi variables is null, although FetchAddressIntentService has already run. How to solve this problem? Sorry For my bad english.. And Thanks For help....

Main Activity Code

```
package com.example.gawaipintarcuaca;

import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import androidx.core.app.ActivityCompat;
import androidx.fragment.app.Fragment;

import android.Manifest;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
import android.location.Geocoder;
import android.location.Location;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.os.ResultReceiver;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.TextView;

import com.google.android.gms.location.FusedLocationProviderClient;
import com.google.android.gms.location.LocationCallback;
import com.google.android.gms.location.LocationRequest;
import com.google.android.gms.location.LocationServices;
import com.google.android.gms.tasks.OnSuccessListener;
import com.google.android.material.bottomnavigation.BottomNavigationView;

import java.lang.reflect.Array;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Calendar;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.Locale;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private TextView lokasi;
    private TextView waktu;
    private FusedLocationProviderClient fusedLocationProviderClient;
    protected Location lastLocation;
    private AddressResultReceiver resultReceiver;
    private LocationCallback locationCallback;
    private TextView suhu;
    public static String kabupaten;
    public static String provinsi;
    private String kodeCuaca;
    private Date date;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        resultReceiver = new AddressResultReceiver(new Handler());
        lokasi = findViewById(R.id.kota);
        date = Calendar.getInstance().getTime();
        waktu = findViewById(R.id.waktu);
        waktu.setText(date.toString());


        //Ambil Lokasi
        fusedLocationProviderClient = LocationServices.getFusedLocationProviderClient(this);

        if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION)
                != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED
                && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION)
                != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(MainActivity.this, new String[]{
                    Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION}, 2);
        }
        fusedLocationProviderClient.getLastLocation()
                .addOnSuccessListener(this, new OnSuccessListener<Location>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onSuccess(Location location) {
                        if (location != null) {
                            lastLocation = location;
                            startIntentService();
                        }
                    }
                });
        startIntentService1();
        suhu = findViewById(R.id.suhu);
    }

    protected void startIntentService(){
        Intent intent = new Intent (this, FetchAddressIntentService.class);
        intent.putExtra(Constants.RECEIVER, resultReceiver);
        intent.putExtra(Constants.LOCATION_DATA_EXTRA, lastLocation);
        startService(intent);
    }

    private void startIntentService1() {
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, ParseXmlCuaca.class);
        Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
        bundle.putString("kabupaten", kabupaten);
        bundle.putString("provinsi", provinsi);
        intent.putExtra("Bundle", bundle);
        startService(intent);
    }

    private class AddressResultReceiver extends ResultReceiver{
        public AddressResultReceiver(Handler handler) {
            super(handler);
        }


        @Override
        protected void onReceiveResult(int resultCode, Bundle resultData) {
            if (resultData == null){
                return;
            }
            String addressOutput = resultData.getString(Constants.RESULT_DATA_KEY);
            kabupaten = resultData.getString("kabupaten");
            String[] kab = kabupaten.split(" ");
            MainActivity.kabupaten = "";
            int kabLength = kab.length;
            for (int i = 1; i < kabLength; i++ ){
                if (i == kabLength - 1){
                    MainActivity.kabupaten += kab[i];
                }
                else{
                    MainActivity.kabupaten += kab[i] + " ";
                }
            }
            MainActivity.provinsi = resultData.getString("provinsi");
            showResult(addressOutput);
        }

        private void showResult(String addressOutput) {
            lokasi.setText(addressOutput);
        }
    }
}
```

FetcAddressIntentService

```
package com.example.gawaipintarcuaca;

import android.app.IntentService;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.location.Address;
import android.location.Geocoder;
import android.location.Location;
import android.nfc.Tag;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.ResultReceiver;
import android.text.TextUtils;
import android.util.Log;

import androidx.annotation.Nullable;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Locale;

public class FetchAddressIntentService extends IntentService {
    public static final String TAG = "Service Lokasi";
    protected ResultReceiver receiver;
    public String provinsi;
    public String kabupaten;

    public FetchAddressIntentService() {
        super(TAG);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onHandleIntent(@Nullable Intent intent) {
        Geocoder geocoder = new Geocoder(this, Locale.getDefault());
        if (intent == null) {
            return;
        }
        String errorMessage = " ";
        Location location = intent.getParcelableExtra(Constants.LOCATION_DATA_EXTRA);

        receiver = intent.getParcelableExtra(Constants.RECEIVER);

        List <Address> addresses = null;

        try{
            addresses = geocoder.getFromLocation(
                    location.getLatitude(),
                    location.getLongitude(),
                    1);
        }
        catch (IOException ioException){
            errorMessage = getString(R.string.service_not_available);
            Log.e(TAG, errorMessage, ioException);
        }
        catch (IllegalArgumentException illegalArgumentException){
            errorMessage = getString(R.string.invalid_lat_long_used);
            Log.e(TAG, errorMessage + ". " + "Latitude = "
                    + location.getLatitude() + ", Longitude = " +
                    location.getLongitude(), illegalArgumentException);
        }
        if (addresses == null || addresses.size() == 0){
            if (errorMessage.isEmpty()){
                errorMessage = getString(R.string.no_address_found);
                Log.e(TAG, errorMessage);
            }
            deliverResultToReceiver(Constants.FAILURE_RESULT, errorMessage);
        }
        else{
            Address address = addresses.get(0);
            ArrayList <String> addressFragments = new ArrayList<String>();

            for (int i = 0 ; i <= address.getMaxAddressLineIndex(); i++){
                addressFragments.add(address.getAddressLine(i));
            }
            Log.i(TAG, getString(R.string.address_found));
            kabupaten = address.getSubAdminArea();
            provinsi = address.getAdminArea();
            deliverResultToReceiver(Constants.SUCCESS_RESULT, TextUtils.join(System.getProperty("line.seperator"),addressFragments));

        }
    }

    private void deliverResultToReceiver(int resultCode, String message) {
        Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
        bundle.putString(Constants.RESULT_DATA_KEY, message);
        bundle.putString("kabupaten", kabupaten);
        bundle.putString("provinsi", provinsi);
        receiver.send(resultCode, bundle);
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you shorten your code down to a [mcve]? At least leave out the imports and shorten the business logic. That way people will be more likely to read through the code.

Comment: Thanks for your advice, I will try your advice

Answer (score 0, accepted):

move `startIntentService1();` from the end of `onCreate` to end of `onReceiveResult` in `AddressResultReceiver`, after you receive and store these two needed variables

currently you are starting `ParseXmlCuaca` `Service` at very beginning of `Activity` lifecycle, before your `Activity` gets location and fetch data in `AddressResultReceiver`. thats why both values are `null`, they aren't initiated (yet)

Comment: Thanks you very much, i will try yout advice